# CDI @Dependent and @New

Tags: cdi

I've two fields in my class:

```
public class Class {

    @Inject private ClassA a;
    @Inject private ClassB b;

    public void search(String lqlSentence)
    {
        this.a.something();
        AnotherClass anotherOne = new AnotherOne;
        anotherOne.method(this.b);
    }
}
```

CDI tells me:

> Unsatisfied dependencies for type ClassA with qualifiers @Default

However, CDI tells me anything about `ClassB b` field.

Then, I've added a `@Dependent` annotation:

```
@Inject @Dependent private ClassA a;
```

CDI tells me the same.

However, if I annotate this field with a `@New` CDI works.

Why if I use `@New` works?
Why CDI doesn't tell me something about the other property `Class B`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This qualifier annotation (`@Dependent`) go on the class definition itself, or the producer for the bean.  Not on the injection point.

Also, don't use `@New`.  its deprecated.  It functions the same as dependent, but is driven from the injection point side whereas CDI is focused on the producer side.

Comment: I still fail to figure out why CDI warns me about `@Inject private ClassA a;` and it tells me nothing about the second field `@Inject private ClassB b;`...

Comment: What do you mean by "warn"? Log messages? Can you share the definitions of each?

Comment: `@Dependent` is *not* a `@Qualifier`, and only serves as `@Scope`. Hence, referring to `@Dependent` as a 'qualifier annotation' is factually incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

CDI in Java EE works with "Types".
So if you have an interface which is being implemented by different classes and you are trying to inject that interface then CDI will complain regarding the type ambiguity coz it wont be able to resolve the type of the bean instance to inject.
For ex:
Lets say we have something like this:

```
public interface UserDao{
   // methods......
}

public class UserDaoMongoImpl implements UserDao{
  //Mongo db implementations....
}

public class UserDaoOrclImpl implements UserDao{
  // oracle Db specific implementations for userDao
}

@Stateless
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

  @Inject private UserDao userDao; //injectPoint

  //service impl ...

}
```

Then here CDI will not be able to determine which implementation to inject coz now we have three different types of UserDao

1. UserDao is a UserDao
2. UserDaoMongoImpl is a UserDao
3. UserDaoOrclImpl is a UserDao

which causes all sorts of confusion for CDI.

Now to overcome this we have qualifiers which are simple Annotations.

So the above code becomes something like:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD,ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface MongoImplementation {
} 

@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD,ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface OrclImplementation {
} 


public interface UserDao{
   // methods......
}

@MongoImplementation
public class UserDaoMongoImpl implements UserDao{
  //Mongo db implementations....
}

@OrclImplementation
public class UserDaoOrclImpl implements UserDao{
  // oracle Db specific implementations for userDao
}

@Stateless
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

  @Inject @MongoImplementation     //Injection point A
  private UserDao mongoUserDao;

  @Inject @OrclImplementation      //Injection point B
  private UserDao orclUserDao;

  //service impl ...

}
```

So now using this CDI will always know which implementation or which type to inject at which injection point and this will not complain about the type ambiguity.